How appropriate is sharing a recommendation letter with a student nowadays?
I've been asked by a student in the US to write a recommendation letter.  I've not written a recommendation letter before (I generally work with younger students), but I know the student well enough to write the letter and he is deserving of a positive letter.
A quick search online tells me that there is much disagreement about the ethical ramifications of either sharing a letter with a student or keeping it a secret.  (As referenced in this question)  Since that question is almost 10 years old now, and it was for college students, I'd like to ask this one:
Is is appropriate for a US student to be allowed to view a letter sent on his behalf?  Why or why not?  And, what are some reasons that I should or should not offer to share the letter?

I have edited the question so that it does not reference undergrad admissions (which is off topic here). Of course, high school teacher recommenders may follow different norms than academic recommenders, but we can only advise about the latter.

Don't share. This relieves letters from the pressure to satisfy the candidate and them being confidential makes them more believable from the perspective of the recipient.
A second, less common, but still possible reason: the student may be disappointed even with a letter that you thought was strong. In some cases, unfortunate formulations may actually trigger lawsuits.
There is no benefit in sharing the letters, but many disadvantages.
In cases where candidates have the right to request access to the recommendation letters, professional candidates know this and waive that right. The only reason not to waive that right is if you suspect the recommender will not provide a constructive letter.
TL;DR: keep it confidential to keep its value.

I have a different view than was expressed by Captain Emacs. I don't claim that you should always show the letter, but think that it is ethically fine to do so. But ethics also assumes that you give an honest appraisal to the institution requesting letters.
When students ask for letters, it is, IMO, valid to let them know if it can't be entirely positive and say why. Give them the opportunity to seek letters elsewhere. You aren't infallible, after all.
I have experience, in fact, that a poorly worded letter by a non-native speaker cost a candidate dearly as the wording gave the exact opposite impression to the reader than intended by the writer. The intent was to be superlative, but that was negated entirely by poor choice of wording. This only came to light years later.
A student might be disappointed, but that might actually be warranted so that they have a more realistic sense of their position.
I would not, however, be very happy in a system that required such sharing.

Wouldn't it be better for a recommender to get advice from a native or near-native speaker or from consulting recommendation advice on the internet? Recommendations are one of the overlooked, but most important part of an academic's job, as they define the future of our students. So, a recommender should learn it properly and not from feedback from the junior candidates who may themselves not really know how to write a recommendation properly. For instance, I know that in Germany, students often underemphasize their own achievements in self-evaluations.

@CaptainEmacs In the case I cited, a colleague of the writer saw the recommendation, but only years later and noted the problem with the candidate. Far too late to make a difference. Yes, it would have been better to have had someone look at it, but not many would think to do so, I'm afraid.

Would showing the letter to the candidate have changed something? The candidate needs also to know what an appropriate letter looks like.
